# Simple mysql insert query giving error

Tags: c#, mysql

This query wont execute its a simple one line query and i dont see any errors in it still it gives error.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Vendors ('Name','Address','Contact','Email','Fax') 
                VALUES('ehsan','tes# 235t','test','testmailcom','test');
```

And error :

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
 your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
 ''Name','Address','Contact','Email','Fax') Values('ehsan','tes# 235t',
              'test','tes' at line 1
```

Here is the actual Code:

```
 cmd = new MySqlCommand("Insert IGNORE into Vendors('Name','Address','Contact','Email','Fax') Values(@name,@address,@contact,@email,@fax)", conn);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", contact);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fax", fax);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MySql, you need to quote the field names with (`)

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Vendors (`Name`,`Address`,`Contact`,`Email`,`Fax`) 
VALUES('ehsan','tes# 235t','test','testmailcom','test');
```

Comment: oh :) . It has been long writing for mysql so i forgot that :) . Cannt accept below 10 minutes but will do when time comes.